# How to manually handle editor dirty state in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm making an editor that manipulates the information of a file through tags.

I made some logic to detect editing these tags, but after a lot of research, I still haven't found a way to manually handle the dirty state of my editor.

With this I can get the reference of my editor:

```
IEditorReference[] ed = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getEditorReferences();

for (IEditorReference iEditorReference : ed) {
   if (iEditorReference.getId().equals(*my editor's id*)) {
     ??? what to do here? ???
   }
}
```

Comment: "Handle" it, meaning do what? Toggle it as dirty (which you can do whenever an edit is made)? Clean?

Comment: set as dirty and at other times set as not dirty... I want to have this control and not leave it to the IDE

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's your editor, it's *always* under your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dirty state of an editor is set by the

```
public boolean isDirty()
```

method implemented by the editor part (defined in the `org.eclipse.ui.ISaveablePart` interface)

Whenever the dirty state changes the editor part must call

```
firePropertyChange(IEditorPart.PROP_DIRTY);
```

If you have an editor reference as shown in your question you would have to call a method that you write in your editor to change the dirty state:

```
MyEditor myEditor = (MyEditor)iEditorReference.getEditor();

myEditor.setDirty();
```

where `setDirty` is a method you write. That method will have to set a flag that `isDirty` can use and call `firePropertyChange`

Comment: how can i call this method in the action of a button (example of study)?

Comment: I added an outline of what you might do to the answer

Comment: sorry for resurrecting this issue, i called `firePropertyChange` many times but i still couldn't get my editor dirty

Comment: Did you override `isDirty` with suitable code? Is Eclipse calling isDirty after you fire the propery change?

Comment: from the debug I could see that the only time it goes through a `setDirty()` is in the `CompatibilityPart` class but it doesn't set it to true

Comment: I don't follow your last comment at all. Did you override `isDirty` in your editor? Are you returning `true` from that when necessary? Is it being called? Show us your code ([edit] the question and add details)

Comment: I found out what seems to be my problem, my editor extends MultiPageEditorPart, the page that does the editing is another class that extends Composite.
I do created my own style, now my question is how do I bind the text fields to dirty the editor when they are modified.

Comment: You will have to use something a modify listener on the text fields and hook them up to your `isDirty` method.